# QuickSort with only two arguments

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, quicksort

How do you construct an algorithm for Quicksort with an array and the length of the array as two arguments?

that is:

```
void quick_sort(int A[], int n)
```

like this.

However, I am only familiar with writing Quicksort with 3 arguments, an array, and the lowest index and the highest index.

the `Quicksort` function below takes 3 arguments, `arr`, `l`, and `h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(int arr[], int l, int h) {
    int pivot = arr[l];
    int i = l;
    int j = h;

    while (i < j) {

        while (arr[i] <= pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (arr[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[i]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[l], &arr[j]);
    return j;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int l, int h) {
    if (l < h) {
        int j = partition(arr, l, h);
        quickSort(arr, l, j - 1);
        quickSort(arr, j + 1, h);
    }
}
```

However, I need to write a QuickSort implementation with only two arguments.

How do you write the function that does the same sorting?
That is, we have only the length of `n`, while the complete quicksort algorithm above has `l` and `h` as arguments.

Comment: You can pass a shortened array. For example, instead of passing (array=arr, startindex=3, length=10) you can pass (array=arr+3, length=10-3).

Comment: `n` is obviously a pretty useless name... What is the second parameter (`int n`) supposed to mean?

Comment: @Alexander Sorry about the confusion. int n means the length of the array.

Comment: @EdmCoff Thank you for your suggestion! I will try that.

Comment: @Haya_05120512 You don't need to apologize.  Alexander was being difficult.  `n` is obviously a perfectly obvious name, in this context.

Comment: @EdmCoff  Thank you for your help. But how do you set the base condition when the quicksort function stops? in this code example that is using l and h, "if(l<h)".

Comment: It's not uncommon to write a recursive function in two parts, an "outer" function to "get the recursion started", and an inner one to do the work.  So you could theoretically implement `quick_sort(int A[], int n)` in terms of `inner_quick_sort(int A[], int start, int n)`.  In this case you don't have to, because EdmCoff's suggestion is the right one, but in other cases, it can be  good way to do it.

Comment: If n==1 would be a good stopping condition if you are using the idea I suggested.

Comment: This implementation is flawed: if `arr[l]` happens to contain the largest value in the slice, the first inner loop will scan the whole slice and keep testing `a[i]` beyond `h`, hence invoking undefined behavior if the slice is at the end of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of code presents a nice interface to the actual work functions. For example, a Quicksort algorithm may present itself as:

```
void quickSort( int * xs, int n );
```

But be implemented as:

```
static int partition( int * xs, int left, int right )
{
  ...
}

static void quickSort_( int * xs, int left, int right )
{
  ...
}

void quickSort( int * xs, int n )
{
  quickSort_( xs, 0, n );
}
```

Notice how the actual workhorse functions are `static` to the library where the user cannot see them.

Comment: Using `size_t` for the `n`, `left` and `right` arguments seems preferable, albeit not the OP's requirement.

Comment: @chqrlie - looking at this again, it's not the typical implementation where unsigned integers is an issue. I deleted my prior comment.